# Best way to code large if-else-statements of Objects in Java?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, hashmap

I'm using Swing and have a JTree in my GUI.  During execution, I parse through the nodes of the tree to determine what action to perform.  Here's a snippet:

```
// action to modify node
public void modifyMenuItem(DefaultMutableTreeNode node)
{
// if node is node 1 in the tree
if(node.equals(treeNodes.node1))
    {
        // perform action 1 
}

 // if node is node 2 in the tree
    else if(node.equals(treeNodes.node2))
    {
        // perform action 2
    }

 // if node is node 3 in the tree
    else if(node.equals(treeNodes.node3))
    {
        // perform action 3
    }
    etc.
}
```

Problem is, I have close to 50 nodes in my tree and I'm afraid that I'm really hurting performance by having this type of implementation.  I have similar if-statements throughout my code.  What is the preferred method for handling large if-statements of Objects like this?  Obviously I can't use a switch statement since these aren't Integer values, so should I create a Hashmap and then use a switch based off the Hash keys?

Comment: are the actions similar to each other?

Comment: Take a look at reflection. Kind of an advanced topic though.

Comment: Why are you having to do all these comparisons? Has a code smell to it.

Comment: If you don't want to use 'if' statements then you could look at Double-Dispatch.

Comment: 50 `if`'s? That's nothing for a computer. And since DefaultMutableTreeNode.equals() relies on pointer comparison, it's absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet is irrelevant in computer time, but is heavily relevant for maintenance tasks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh yes, I am not denying that, but the assumption that 50 if's are the source of the problem is incorrect.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I understand that, but I have several of these if-statements in my code.  I'm new to Java and would like to know how to code them the "proper" way to enforce good habits.

Comment: @Brian Roach I have a popupMenu that is assigned to each node.  When the user selects an option from the popupMenu, I need to figure out which node the popup action refers to, so I grab the last selected node with `tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent()` and then have to do these giant comparisons to perform a different action depending on which node it is.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @jlordo Yes, the actions are all pretty much the same.  For this example, I want to display a different JPanel depending on the node that is passed into the method.

Comment: @Matt and the action you need to perform is dependent on the position of the node in the tree? Or just which node it is?

Comment: NM, looking at your code - it's which node it is. See JB's answer below. You want to encapsulate what you need to do inside the node via the Object stored in it, then there's no comparisons necessary - you already know the selected node.

Comment: @BrianRoach Took me a little while to understand what he meant, but I think I got it now.  I'm still a newbie programmer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use polymorphism:

```
public void modifyMenuItem(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    ((MyUserObject) node.getUserObject()).doAction();
}
```

For this to work, all the user objects of your nodes must be instances of the same `MyUserObject` interface.

Comment: +1, alternatively he could implement `TreeNode` or extend `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and add his required methods.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  Create a class that contains the specific action(s) a node will perform.  Then when I define my DefaultMutableTreeNode, use this class as my userObject. Did I follow that correctly?

Comment: @Matt - Yep, that's it. He's also suggesting create an interface that class would implement (defines `doAction()`) which makes it even more flexible if need be.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I got this method working and my code is so much easier to read and maintainable now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing more what you are trying to do, I'd suggest you use polymorphism. You create subclasses of `DefaultMutableTreeNode` that also implement an interface of yours, let's call it `ActionPerfomer` with a method `performAction()`. You use instances of those classes as Nodes in your Tree and then can simply write:

```
// I suppose you can't change the signature?
public void modifyMenuItem(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    if (node instanceof ActionPerfomer) {
        ActionPerfomer ap = (ActionPerfomer) node;
        ap.performAction();
    } else {
        logger.log("How did that get here?");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: you took the time to choose a good name for the interface

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a map with 50 items, keyed on the different treenodes (or treenode names), and returning an 'Action' that can be performed on the node?

```
Map<String, Action> map = new HashMap<String, Action>();
// populate the map with items and Actions

Action action = map.get(node.getName());
action.perform(node);
```

Either the treenodes need to implement equals and hashcode correctly... or you can just use the node name (given it is unique).

Good luck!

Comment: *The treenodes need to implement equals and hashcode correctly*, based in your example, you can use the node text as the `String` key (that already implements these functions).